# Is aptitude still considered superior to apt-get?

Tags: apt, aptitude, package-management

When I first started with Ubuntu using `aptitude` was the 'in-thing', with some stated improvements over `apt-get`. Am I correct in saying that `apt-get` has now 'caught up' with `aptitude`, and it makes little difference which is used (although it is preferable to choose one or the other, and stick with it)?

Moreover, with `aptitude` set to be removed from a default Ubuntu install, should everyone revert to `apt-get`, especially when guiding new users interested in the CLI?

Comment: the cool kids today use `apt` instead of either of those : https://itsfoss.com/apt-vs-apt-get-difference/

Comment: `aptitude why` is handy sometimes, and [there isn't a real equivalent](https://askubuntu.com/questions/424150/what-is-apt-get-equivalent-of-aptitude-why).

Answer (score 134, accepted):

As far as I can see, in 10.04, the main differences between aptitude
and apt-get are:

1. `aptitude` adds explicit per-package flags, indicating whether a
   package was automatically installed to satisfy a dependency: you
   can manipulate those flags (`aptitude markauto` or `aptitude unmarkauto`) to change the way aptitude treats the package.

   `apt-get` keeps track of the same information, but will not show it
   explicitly. `apt-mark` can be used for manipulating the flags.
2. `aptitude` will offer to remove unused packages each time you
   remove an installed package, whereas `apt-get` will only do that if
   explicitly asked to with `apt-get autoremove` or specify `--auto-remove`.
3. `aptitude` acts as a single command-line front-end to most of the
   functionalities in both `apt-get` and `apt-cache`. **Note**: As of 16.04, there is an `apt` command that includes the most commonly used commands from `apt-get` and `apt-cache` and a few extra features.
4. In contrast to `apt-cache`'s "search", `aptitude`'s "search" output
   also shows the installed/removed/purged status of a package (plus
   aptitude's own status flags).  Also, the "install" output marks
   which packages are being installed to satisfy a dependency, and
   which are being removed because unused.
5. `aptitude` has a (text-only) interactive UI.

I personally use only `aptitude` for my command-line package
management (and I never use the text UI); I find its output more
readable than `apt-get`/`apt-cache`.

However, if `aptitude` will be no longer standard on Ubuntu, there's
no other choice than use `apt-get` in instructions and how-to
documents.

(Personally, I'm rather disappointed to see it go away in 10.10;
especially since the improvements of aptitude over `apt-get` are
mostly on the usability side.  I guess they deemed that those
conversant with the command-line know how to get aptitude back, and
those who don't use the command-line will not care...)

Comment: aptitude search'es on package names, apt-cache on package name+description

(We will just have to start every howto with `sudo apt-get install aptitude`)

Comment: 2. However apt-get will tell you that there are unused packages and that you can remove them with `apt-get autoremove`.

Comment: One of the disadvantages of aptitude is the inability to consider pinning as done by apt-get

Comment: Aptitude correctly reads `/etc/apt/preferences` (and the pinning therein), but [currently](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=557580) ignores `/etc/apt/preferences.d/`.  It's a [known bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=557580) so there is hope for it to be fixed soon.

Comment: Would you mind if I removed all the backticks? All that (visual) noise makes this unreadable, even though it's a good answer.

Comment: @Roger: thanks for the suggestion, I kept only thos that were grouping two or more words.  Feel free to edit more.

Comment: Aptitude has an option to retrieve the changelog easily: `aptitude changelog package-name`. I am not aware of such feature in `apt-get`.

Comment: @RiccardoMurri for quick ref, it was marked Fixed in version 0.6.3-3.2 @ 18 Oct 2010

Comment: What it an equivalent of `apt-get autoremove` with `aptitude`?  I have old kernels that `apt-get autoremove` suggests me to remove, but i see no way to remove them with `aptitude`.

Comment: @sepp2k It seems the behaviour of apt-get is different from the behaviour of aptitude in this regard, see the remark by Alexey above and the question http://askubuntu.com/questions/889771/how-to-make-aptitude-clean-up-old-kernels.

Answer (score 21):

I guess it's a matter of personal choice by now. I find typing `aptitude search` makes more sense to me than `apt-cache search`, and I like that it tells me which packages I have installed right there in the search output, instead of having to run `dpkg -l`.

Comment: +1 Agreed being able to see if an application is installed while searching is very handy. Although I do find that apt-cache search is a lot faster than aptitude search.

Comment: I use a two-letter bash alias for apt-cache search, or I would probably be using `aptitude search` as well.

Comment: I've noticed that `apt-get`'s search is a bit more thorough than `aptitude`. The latter seems to only look at the package name, while the former also searches descriptions, I think. e.g. try searching for `build-essential`.

Answer (score 13):

Earlier apt-get would not manage dependencies properly and therefore cause orphaned dependencies to remain in a system even after the package that was using them was uninstalled - this is not longer the case, to remove orphaned dependencies use

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

aptitude always did this right and tracks dependencies better, but now both package managers do the job.

On ubuntu it is better to use apt-get because its supported and endorsed by the company, on debian I would use aptitude

Comment: The last statement is not accurate. `aptitude` is supported just fine on Ubuntu and it is installed by default. There's no difference between Ubuntu and Debian in that regard, either.

Comment: It is being removed from the default install in 10.10

Comment: In my experience, `aptitude` has always been worse at tracking installed dependencies.  It tended to remove unrelated ones when removing a program, and ended up breaking other programs in the process...

Comment: What it an equivalent of `apt-get autoremove` with `aptitude`?  I have old kernels that `apt-get autoremove` suggests me to remove, but i see no way to remove them with `aptitude`.

Comment: @Alexey You can use `aptitude remove '~g'`. ([Source](https://aptitude.alioth.debian.org/doc/en/ch02s04s05.html#searchGarbage)) Note that `aptitude` will automatically offer to remove unused dependencies when removing packages with it.

Comment: @nyuszika7h, `aptitude search '~g'` found only `linux-signed-image`, and i could remove it by running `aptitude install`.  After that `aptitude search '~g'` does not find anything else, but `apt autoremove` proposes to remove `linux-headers`, `linux-image`, `linux-image-extra`...

Answer (score 6):

In addition to the other answers, it's also worth noting that `apt-get` often falls on its face for simple operations, and it has no ability to handle dependency version mismatches or broken packages (although it claims that broken packages can be fixed with `apt-get install -f`, I've literally never seen that work in my entire life).

For some reason, I still use `apt-get` by default, but when it encounters problems, I usually end up resolving them with `aptitude`, which never seems to encounter `apt-get`'s numerous problems.

Comment: I also have similar experience with resolving conflicts, `aptitude` is a way better alternative in that sense.

Comment: For the record, I just saw   apt-get install -f   fix my system.
aptitude had problems, this fixed it, and then first thing I did was apt install aptitude :)   Choice is a good thing(tm)

Answer (score 3):

I would say that in my personal experience aptitude and apt-get have very similar functionality.

The main difference that come to mind that might effect a users choices are, that aptitude offers an ncurses interface and that it offers options for safe-upgrade and full-upgrade that can come in handy.

Personally I always use apt-get and recommend that new users use apt-get as well. With aptitude set to be removed from Ubuntu by default as you said, this still seems to be the best recommendation. 
As if they did want to use aptitude they will need to know how to use apt-get to install aptitude if they want it :)

Comment: could you explain what an ncurses interface is please?

Comment: @fluteflute: ncurses is a library used to realize text user interface. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses

Answer (score 2):

On a server I prefer Atitude because it comes with a pretty good interface to check package changelogs, selective upgrades and that kinds of stuff. apt-get is more quick though and I always use that if I just want to update everything without too much hassle.