# What are benefits of aptitude compared to apt-get?

Tags: apt, aptitude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is aptitude really better than apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-really-better-than-apt-get)

To install a package I can "apt-get install" or "aptitude install", to search - "apt-cache search" or "aptitude search". I find these things pretty similar. So what are benefits of aptitude?

Comment: Duplicate: [Is aptitude really better than apt-get?](http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-really-better-than-apt-get)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has a more advanced dependency handling feature and a graphical front-end. On the whole it does not matter and lately I have been using apt-get instead. I believe it also tries to roll the apt-* features into one program.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29