# Can't upgrade packages, it gets stuck on openjdk-6-jre-headless

Tags: 10.10, server, dpkg, openjdk

I am using Ubuntu Maverick (server).

When I run:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

it gets stuck on:

```
Setting up openjdk-6-jre-headless (6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1) ...
```

Why? And what can I do to stop it?

I tried removing it with `apt-get` but get this error:

> E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

So then I tried this:

```
dpkg --purge openjdk-6-jre-headless
```

I got this:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of openjdk-6-jre-headless:
 openjdk-6-jre-lib depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b17).
 ca-certificates-java depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b16-1.6.1-2) | java6-runtime-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless is to be removed.
  Package java6-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless which provides java6-runtime-headless is to be removed.
 ca-certificates-java depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b16-1.6.1-2) | java6-runtime-headless; however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless is to be removed.
  Package java6-runtime-headless is not installed.
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless which provides java6-runtime-headless is to be removed.
dpkg: error processing openjdk-6-jre-headless (--purge):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-6-jre-headless
```

The thing is I think my DB is using it... Not sure... I am using Cassandra with Thrift...

Yes, it's getting a bit more complex...

```
# dpkg --configure -a
```

I get:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openjdk-6-jre:
 openjdk-6-jre depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (>= 6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing openjdk-6-jre (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libaccess-bridge-java:
 libaccess-bridge-java depends on default-jre | openjdk-6-jre | sun-java6-jre; however:
  Package default-jre is not installed.
  Package openjdk-6-jre is not configured yet.
  Package sun-java6-jre is not installed.
dpkg: error processing libaccess-bridge-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icedtea-6-jre-cacao:
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao depends on openjdk-6-jre-headless (= 6b20-1.9.7-0ubuntu1); however:
  Package openjdk-6-jre-headless is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing icedtea-6-jre-cacao (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libaccess-bridge-java-jni:
 libaccess-bridge-java-jni depends on libaccess-bridge-java (>= 1.26.2-5); however:
  Package libaccess-bridge-java is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing libaccess-bridge-java-jni (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openjdk-6-jre
 libaccess-bridge-java
 icedtea-6-jre-cacao
 libaccess-bridge-java-jni
```

Thanks again for any help.

Comment: Try to run: `sudo aptitude reinstall openjdk-6-jre-headless`.
If that doesn't work, run a:  `sudo aptitude purge openjdk-6-jre-headless` and post the output here ;-)

Comment: What is the difference between aptitude and apt-get?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/1743/6969. The apt-get equivalent would be `sudo apt-get --reinstall install openjdk-6-jre-headless` and `sudo apt-get purge openjdk-6-jre-headless`

Comment: It seems it is a problem with Amazon EC2.

Comment: There package manager...

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Let me look into it. I think it was solved.

Comment: Java uses a crap load of memory, make sure you have some available. I ran into this error before and had the problem go away after purchasing additional ram.

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a well known bug with t1.micro instances on EC2

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-ec2/+bug/634487

Note that this is fixed in US-WEST-2:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-ec2/+bug/634487/comments/69

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I know this is kind of an old issue, but I encountered it on a system (which was obviously not patched for some time), and I finally got it working with :

```
dpkg --force-all -P openjdk-6-jre-headless
apt-get update
apt-get -f install
```

(`--force-all` is important)
Afterwards, I could upgrade the system