# do-release-upgrade hangs at downloading openjdk-6-jre-headless

Tags: upgrade

I'm trying to do `do-release-upgrade` (also tried the graphical version before - same issue with less details).

It always get stuck downloading openjdk-6-jre-headless. The exact line

```
3% [18 openjdk-6-jre-headless 27.1 MB/27.3 MB 99%]
```

It always exactly downloads 27.1 MB, then stops and then it tries again. I already changed the server but no difference (tried http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ and http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ so far).

The direct link to the file is [this](http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openjdk-6/openjdk-6-jre-headless_6b24-1.11.4-1ubuntu0.12.04.1_i386.deb). This file is about 26 MB (again different?).

Why is this? What's the problem? How can I fix it? Or work around it?

There are some similar questions, e.g. [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48656/cant-upgrade-packages-it-gets-stuck-on-openjdk-6-jre-headless) or[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/190828/apt-get-upgrade-stuck-at-the-same-package). The suggestions cannot really be applied for `do-release-upgrade`, though (or at least I don't know how).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this can count as an answer but I post it anyway because this is how I solved it now:

It seemed that it already modified my sources.conf with the precise (the latest Ubuntu) release. So I just tried with both `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Initially, I got similar problems with openjdk-6-jre-headless but with some back and forth (I think mostly because of `apt-get distupgrade`), this somehow resolved. However, this also didn't finished completely and I got a very much messed up system.

Some follow up questions:

- [Could not perform immediate configuration on 'util-linux'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197528/could-not-perform-immediate-configuration-on-util-linux)
- [packages been kept back](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197527/packages-been-kept-back)
- [trying to overwrite ... which is also in package ...](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197534/trying-to-overwrite-which-is-also-in-package)

After I got this all resolved, I tried the `do-release-upgrade` again and it seems to work now.