# packages been kept back

Tags: upgrade, apt, aptitude

I tried both `aptitude -y safe-upgrade` and `apt-get upgrade -f` but in both cases, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
... (long list)
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 903 not upgraded.
```

I guess this resulted from several hacks where I tried to update my system (trying to work around [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197515/do-release-upgrade-hangs-at-downloading-openjdk-6-jre-headless) problem).

My question now: Why are they kept back? What can I do to install them?

---

On a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/601/the-following-packages-have-been-kept-back-why-and-how-do-i-solve-it), I got the suggestion to just use `apt-get dist-upgrade` instead. However, that fails at the moment for me because of:

`E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'util-linux'.Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)`

This is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197528/could-not-perform-immediate-configuration-on-util-linux) problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I did `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev` ([because](https://askubuntu.com/a/197531/6878)), this resolved all the kept-back packages (well, or maybe it was my `apt-get dist-upgrade` which I did after that, which failed though).

Comment: `apt-get dist-upgrade` is a likely fix for the typical "packages have been kept back" message. This helped on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, not sure about other releases.