# Could not perform immediate configuration on 'util-linux'

Tags: upgrade, dist-upgrade

I am trying to do `apt-get dist-upgrade` but I get the error:

`E: Could not perform immediate configuration on 'util-linux'.Please see man 5 apt.conf under APT::Immediate-Configure for details. (2)`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: My answer doesn;t apply now. Honestly, I don't know what to do, so I deleted my answer.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ: It was still helpful, though, because of the `-O APT::Immediate-Configure=0` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Messed up system, I guess.

I tried to do `apt-get dist-upgrade -o APT::Immediate-Configure=0` but I got a dependency cycle error: `E: Couldn't configure pre-depend multiarch-support for libnih-dbus1, probably a dependency cycle.`

Then I tried to `apt-get install -f libnih-dbus1` and got another error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  libc6-dev: Breaks: cmake (< 2.8.4+dfsg.1-5) but 2.8.1-4~lucid1 is to be installed
E: Broken packages`
```

Then I tried `sudo apt-get install libc6-dev` which worked.

Then I did `apt-get install util-linux -f -o APT::Immediate-Configure=0` which also worked fine.

So I think this problem is resolved now.