# Get package description using apt

Tags: apt, package-management, info

How do I get the prosaic description of a package using `apt`? I tried both `apt-cache show` and `apt-cache showpkg` but no luck.

Using synaptic it's easy as typing the package name and the description is given by the standard view, but sometimes I'd prefer to just use apt-cache, for example from terminal.

Comment: `apt-cache show` shows the package description int the `Description:` field. What else are you looking for?

Comment: "apt-cache show <package name>" shows the Description if the package is known to the system.  In what way is it not working for you?

Comment: @enzotib I oversighted the output. `apt-cache show` does exactly the thing I asked for.

Answer (score 23):

If you would just use `apt-cache search package-name`, all packages with "package-name" in it would be returned. To limit to a package named "package-name", use:

```
apt-cache search ^package-name$
```

Comment: strange, for example `apt-cache search ^vim$` doesn't **only** find the `vim` package, but some more, but not all, that `apt-cache search ^vim` finds ???

Comment: @rubo77 `apt-cache search ^vim$` also lists other packages like `vim-gtk` because that package *provides* the vim package. You can check that with `apt-cache show vim-gtk`.

Comment: so with an extra grep you can narrow the result to only the package: http://askubuntu.com/a/898398/34298

Comment: Regarding your comment from 30 mar 2017 at 12:12, the regex `^..$` does not list other packages, only one between the regex delimiters.

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with [`aptitude`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/aptitude) as in:

```
aptitude show package-name
```

See also [Is aptitude still considered superior to apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-still-considered-superior-to-apt-get)

Comment: This is almost the same as `apt show`, check with eg `colordiff -y --suppress-common-lines <(apt-cache show feh) <(aptitude show feh)`

Answer (score 8):

`apt-cache show <packagename>` does what you want. You might have overseen it. The following command highlights it:

```
apt-cache show scons | grep --color -E "Description|$"
```

Comment: why the heck can't we do `apt show --description --maintainer<package>`?

Comment: @ÉdouardLopez You could make a feature request: https://github.com/Debian/apt/issues

Answer (score 5):

[Lekensteyn answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/49585/349837) is great to get the short description. Extending [Martin's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/600278/349837) you can get also the larger multi-line description (also [in other languages](https://askubuntu.com/a/78225/349837)):

```sh
apt-cache show figlet toilet | grep -E "^Package|^Description-en|^ "
```

If you use this a lot you can add this function to your `.bashrc`/`.zshrc`:

```sh
apt-desc() { apt-cache show "$@" | grep -E "^Package|^Description-en|^ "; }
```

For a normal case just use the friendlier [`apt show`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt.8.html).

Comment: In your regex, `Package` means to color Package in red or whatever default highlight color is and `|^` to output the rest in standard color?

Comment: The [`|` acts like an OR operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). Paste any regex on sites like [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/) or [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to learn more. Remove match highlight (usually in red) by adding [`--color=never` to grep options](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/grep.1.html#options).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are looking for a specific package, I believe the following is what you are in search of:

```
apt-cache search some-pkg
```

If I have misunderstood what you are trying to do, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Strange, for example apt-cache search ^vim$ doesn't only find the vim package, but some more, but not all, that apt-cache search ^vim finds.

So better use this:

```
PACKAGE=vim
apt-cache search ^$PACKAGE$|egrep "^$PACKAGE -"
```