# Lost 'System Settings' on Ubuntu Precise Pangolin x86_64

Tags: 12.04, gnome, 64-bit, settings, system

I am new here. I was facing issues with emacs-snapshot sourced from a PPA, so I tried following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/103100/69375) (blindly =/), and

```
sudo apt-get remove `apt-cache search emacs | awk '{print $1}'` --purge
```

took out a big chunk of Ubuntu 12.04 including Software Center, System Settings and probably a few other things that I am not immediately missing. I was able to install Software Center back with which I tried to install System Settings unsuccessfully (it tried to install the KDE version).

Does anyone know how I can get System Settings back without reinstalling Ubuntu?

PS: I am also missing the clock on the top-right which is usually next to the menu button containing shutdown/display/etc. settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

should get you every thing back that is installed by default. Replace `ubuntu-desktop` with `kubuntu-desktop` if you are using Kubuntu (KDE).

Comment: Did you know you can accidentally uninstall individual settings from the system settings. This fixed it.