# Ubuntu 14.04 - Software Center - Edit->Software Sources disabled

Tags: 14.04, software-center, software-sources

The button in *Software Center→Edit→Software sources...* is disabled.

Is there another way to reach it or simple enable the button? What could be causing it?

If I know I can fix it myself and avoid happening again. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figured everything out.

For some reason, my **System Settings** process was called `gnome-control-center`. Since it seemed buggy, I removed it:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge gnome-control-center
```

... expecting to then reinstall it to see if it would behave better.

After the uninstall I tried to access it from the top right system button and guess what... It DID show up with all the configuration buttons!

I have two guesses:

1. The distro upgrader changed the **System Settings** program but didn't update the name entry for the menu, because the package was there the whole time;

OR

2. At some forgotten point I installed gnome packages and screwed up Ubuntu's evolution. Then the distro upgrader didn't recognize it or or opted out to leave my choice of using a gnome tool instead of, maybe, "unity control center"?

Anyway. There is the info for anyone crossing this issue. I have seen other people in the same situation around the web. I hope this helps someone.

---

**Editor's Addition** [(by Anwar)](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/462875/2)

It's the installation of gnome packages and not removing them cleanly. `gnome-control-center` is GNOME3 sessions part and not meant to be used in Unity.

Comment: It's the second one. gnome-control-center is a gnome3 part, unity-control-center is the Unity component.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there another way to reach it ... ?

I think you can directly access it through **Software & Updates** either from the dashboard or from the **System Settings** panel (in the shutdown button).

Now for the second part of the problem:

Try reinstalling `ubuntu-desktop` as [proposed here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148334/lost-system-settings-on-ubuntu-precise-pangolin-x86-64)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Raph. Actually, I don't know if it was there before, but...

Comment: Damn! After searching for over an hour. I just realized that the software sources needed to be manually reinstalled after the upgrade from 13.10.

It can be installed from the Software Center. The package is called "software-properties-gtk" or "software-properties-kde", if you want to install it from the command line.

Now that was really weird. I guess it is not installed by default because it is technical application and occupies 260MB in the hard drive.

Comment: In my opinion, given that I upgraded from a system that had it, it should keep having it!
If I was going for a fresh install, I'd like to have a check box like this: "[ ] install basic technical tools?". Or something like that, because it is actual infra-structure. It could go in the same step where you check a box for Flash.

I won't bother reporting directly to Canonical, because they must have realized this confusion already.

Cheers!

Comment: Oh! And I had already completely removed ubuntu-desktop and and reinstalled it. It was my first trial, by the way. Wipe everything away and replace... sounds like the perfect idea :D See my replies to my own question. The problem was a bit more obscure. Thank you very much for your time and experience :)

Answer (score 0):

In Kubuntu 14.04 use Muon Discover. Just type `muon discover` in the search field of Kmenu or go to

**Kmenu > applications > system > software center (Muon  discover) [with blue icon].

In muon discover choose the "sources" tab at the top of the window. Then click on **configure software sources** in the top right corner, enter your password, and enjoy!