# emacs25 and emacs26 from a PPA cannot coexist

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, emacs

I have installed `emacs25` from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~kelleyk/+archive/ubuntu/emacs, and it coexisted well with emacs 24 from the repositories (Ubuntu 16.04). Now that `emacs26` is available from the same PPA, I thought I could have all three versions installed. However `emacs26` cannot be installed since it shares some files with `emacs25`, and I cannot remove whatever files were installed with `emacs26`.

I tried to follow the advice from: [Unable to install Emacs 24 from ppa:cassou/emacs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91129/unable-to-install-emacs-24-from-ppacassou-emacs), but

```
sudo apt-get remove `apt-cache search emacs | awk '{print $1}'` --purge
```

gives:

```
~$ sudo apt-get remove `apt-cache search emacs | awk '{print $1}'` --purge
[sudo] password for rafael: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'anthy' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'anthy-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'auctex' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'bbdb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'devhelp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs-goodies-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'exuberant-ctags' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'fetchmail' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gettext-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libanthy-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libanthy0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'tmux' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'acl2-emacs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'agda' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'agda-bin' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'agda-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'agda-stdlib' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'agda-stdlib-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'alot' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'alot-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'anthy-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'anything-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'apel' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'aplus-fsf-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ats2-lang' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'auto-complete-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'auto-install-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'bbdb3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'bhl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'bitmap-mule' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'c-sig' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'cafeobj-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'chktex' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'cl-iterate' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'cl-swank' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'clang-format-3.5' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'clang-format-3.6' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'clang-format-3.7' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'cmuscheme48-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'colordiff' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'commit-patch' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'common-lisp-controller' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'coq' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'crypt++el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'cvc3-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'cxref-emacs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'darcsum' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dash-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ddskk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'debian-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'develock-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'devscripts-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dh-elpa' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dictem' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dictionary-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dmtcp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dmtcp-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'docbook2x' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'doxymacs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'dpkg-dev-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'e2wm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'e3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'eblook' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ecasound-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ecb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'edb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'edict-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'eflite' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'egg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'el-get' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'eldav' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-aggressive-indent' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-async' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-circe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-company' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-editorconfig' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-epl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-expand-region' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-f' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-flx' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-flx-ido' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-geiser' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-git-commit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-helm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-helm-core' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-js2-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-magit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-magit-popup' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-markdown-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-noflet' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-persp-projectile' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-perspective' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-pkg-info' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-popup' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-projectile' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-rust-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-sml-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-vala-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elpa-with-editor' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elscreen' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'elserv' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs-calfw' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs-calfw-howm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs-intl-fonts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs-jabber' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs-nox' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs-window-layout' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacspeak' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacspeak-espeak-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacspeak-ss' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emms' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'erc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ess' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'etktab' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'evernote-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'eweouz' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'flim' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'geiser' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ghc-mod' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ghc-mod-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'global' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gmult' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gnat-gps' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gnats' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gnats-user' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gnu-smalltalk-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gnuplot-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gnuserv' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'goby' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gocode-auto-complete-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'golang-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gramadoir' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'gri-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'haml-elisp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'haskell-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'howm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'icicles' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'id-utils' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'idl-font-lock-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ilisp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ilisp-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'info2man' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'inform-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'initz' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'inotify-hookable' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'irony-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ispell' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'jed' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'jedit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'joe' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'jove' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'js2-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'jupp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'kdesdk-scripts' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'kxterm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'latex-cjk-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ledger-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ledit' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libconfig-find-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libghc-agda-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libghc-agda-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libghc-pandoc-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libghc-pandoc-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libghc-pandoc-prof' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libgnu-regexp-java' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libkkc-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libkkc-data' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libkkc-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libkkc-utils' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libkkc-utils-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libkkc2' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libkkc2-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'liblatex-table-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libledit-ocaml-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libocp-indent-lib-ocaml' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libocp-indent-lib-ocaml-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libparse-exuberantctags-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libpcre-ocaml' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libpcre-ocaml-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libproc-invokeeditor-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libre-ocaml-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'librep-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'librep16' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'librobert-hooke-clojure' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libtext-findindent-perl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libutop-ocaml' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'libutop-ocaml-dev' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'liece' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'liece-dcc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'liquidsoap-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'lisaac-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'lookup-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'lsdb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'lua-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'lyskom-elisp-client' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'malaga-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'maxima-emacs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mew' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mew-beta' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mgp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mh-e' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mhc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mhc-utils' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'midge' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'migemo-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'minlog' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mit-scheme' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mit-scheme-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mit-scheme-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mksh' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mmm-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mpg123-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mpqc-support' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mu-cite' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'mu4e' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'muse-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'navi2ch' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nescc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nethack-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nethack-lisp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ng-cjk' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ng-cjk-canna' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ng-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ng-latin' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nmh' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'nomarch' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'notmuch-addrlookup' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'notmuch-emacs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ocaml-core' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ocaml-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ocp-indent' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'oneliner-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'org-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'otags' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'pandoc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'pandoc-data' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'paredit-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'php-elisp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'planner-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'post-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'prolog-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'proofgeneral' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'proofgeneral-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'psgml' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'pylint3' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'pymacs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'pyrex-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-editor' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-rope' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-ropemacs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python-ropemode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'python3-editor' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'rabbit-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'rail' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ranger' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'rdtool-elisp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'refdb-clients' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'refdb-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'refdb-server' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'refdb-www' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'remembrance-agent' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'rep' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'rep-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'riece' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'rnc-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ruby-github-markup' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'ruby-org' is not installed, so not removed
Package 's-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'sass-elisp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'sawfish' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'scala-mode-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'search-ccsb' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'search-citeseer' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'select-xface' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'semi' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'sepia' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'silversearcher-ag-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'singular-ui-emacs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'sisu' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'slime' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'speechd-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'speechd-el-doc-cs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'speechd-up' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'stow' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'stumpwm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'supercollider-emacs' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'sylpheed' is not installed, so not removed
Package 't-code' is not installed, so not removed
Package 't-code-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'tdiary-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'tiarra-conf-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'timidity-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'tkcon' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'tpp' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'tuareg-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'tweak' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'twittering-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'txt2regex' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'tzc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'uim-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'uim-latin' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'urweb-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'utop' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'uzbl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'verbiste-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'vile' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'vile-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'vile-filters' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'vim-voom' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'vm' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'w3m-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'w3m-el-snapshot' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'whizzytex' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'windows-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'wl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'wl-beta' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'wordwarvi' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'wordwarvi-sound' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'wysihtml-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'x-face-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xcite' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xcscope-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-basesupport' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-basesupport-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-bin' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-mule' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-mule-canna-wnn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-mulesupport' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-mulesupport-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-nomule' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-support' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xemacs21-supportel' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xfonts-bitmap-mule' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xfonts-kapl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xfonts-terminus-oblique' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xfonts-thai-etl' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xfonts-thai-poonlap' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xjed' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xstow' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xul-ext-exteditor' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'xvile' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'yaml-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'yasnippet' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'yasnippet-snippets' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'yasr' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'yatex' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'yc-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'yorick' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'zeal' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'zeal-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'zile' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'org-mode-doc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'sdic' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'wnn7egg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'x-pgp-sig-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs24-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs24-lucid-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs24-nox' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs24-nox-dbg' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'erlang-tools' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'clang-format-3.8' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'clang-format-3.9' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'clang-format-4.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'clang-format-5.0' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs-mozc' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs-mozc-bin' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs24-lucid' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'erlang' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'erlang-mode' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'git-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'idn' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'puppet-el' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs25-nox' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs26-common' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'emacs26-nox' is not installed, so not removed
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aspell : Depends: dictionaries-common (> 0.40) but it is not going to be installed
 aspell-en : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 0.49.2) but it is not going to be installed
 aspell-es : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 1.23~) but it is not going to be installed
 groovy2 : Depends: libjline2-java but it is not going to be installed
 hunspell-en-us : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) but it is not going to be installed
 hyphen-en-us : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) but it is not going to be installed or
                         openoffice.org-updatedicts
 mythes-en-us : Depends: dictionaries-common but it is not going to be installed
 openoffice.org-hyphenation : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 0.10) but it is not going to be installed or
                                       openoffice.org-updatedicts
 wbritish : Depends: dictionaries-common (>= 0.20) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
~$
```

and then `sudo apt-get -f install` gives:

```
~$ sudo apt-get -f install 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  emacs26-common
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  emacs26-common
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 117 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/17.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 71.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 337093 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../emacs26-common_26.1~1.git07f8f9b-kk1+16.04_all.deb ...
Unpacking emacs26-common (26.1~1.git07f8f9b-kk1+16.04) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs26-common_26.1~1.git07f8f9b-kk1+16.04_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/subdirs.el', which is also in package emacs25-common 25.3~1.gite0284ab-kk1+16.04
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20180209-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/emacs26-common_26.1~1.git07f8f9b-kk1+16.04_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
~$
```

I have also tried `sudo apt-get autoremove`, with no luck.

How should I proceed? I am not insisting to have both versions 25 and 26 coexisting anymore, I just want a working Ubuntu system with either.

EDIT: I am inserting the results of `remove` and `purge` commands.

```
$ sudo apt remove emacs25
[sudo] password for rafael: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs26 : Depends: emacs26-common but it is not going to be installed
 emacs26-el : Depends: emacs26-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
~$ sudo apt remove emacs26
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs26-el : Depends: emacs26-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
~$ sudo apt purge emacs25
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs26 : Depends: emacs26-common but it is not going to be installed
 emacs26-el : Depends: emacs26-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
~$ sudo apt purge emacs26
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 emacs26-el : Depends: emacs26-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
~$
```

After this, the result of `sudo apt-get -f install` is identical to the shown above.

Comment: How about `sudo apt remove` the one you don't want?

Comment: How about `sudo apt purge` the one you don't want.

Comment: @fkraiem @waltinator both commands return the message that `emacs26` and `emacs26-el` have unmet dependencies, and suggest to run `apt-get -f install` wtih no packages. Running that gives exactly the same as in the original post.

Comment: `purge` has nothing to do with unmet dependencies; it only removes config files... Anyway, as usual please provide the full and exact command you ran and output it produced.

Comment: @fkraiem I have edited the question inserting the output of the mentioned commands.

Comment: You can see that when you try to remove `emacs26`, Apt no longer complains about its unmet dependencies (since it is to be removed), but there is also `emacs26-el` that has unmet dependencies, so you should remove both *together*: `sudo apt remove emacs26 emacs26-el`.

Comment: @fkraiem Thanks, it worked indeed! Please turn your comment to an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two packages, `emacs26` and `emacs26-el`, have an unmet dependency, `emacs26-common`. In such cases, Apt suggests running `apt-get -f install` to install the missing dependency, but installing `emacs26-common` failed due to a conflict with currently-installed `emacs25-common`. Thus one must instead first remove `emacs26` and `emacs26-el` (`apt remove emacs26 emacs26-el`) to put Apt back to a normal state, and then possibly remove `emacs25` and all related packages before installing `emacs26`.

Answer (score 3):

As described by @fkraiem, installation of `emacs26-common` conflicts with `emacs25-common`. The following steps worked well for me:

**Notice:** this will *delete* Emacs25 from your system.

```
sudo apt purge emacs26
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt purge emacs25
sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update
sudo apt install emacs26
```