# How can I make apt-get upgrade the kernel, similarly to aptitude?

Tags: upgrade, apt, aptitude

Installed new Ubuntu Server 12.04 on Windows Azure

After `apt-get upgrade`, console shows:

```bsh
The following packages have been kept back:
  linux-image-extra-virtual linux-image-virtual linux-tools linux-virtual
(...)

83 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
Need to get 64.5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 714 kB of additional disk space will be used
```

And After aptitude upgrade

```bsh
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-3.2.0-32-virtual{a} linux-image-extra-3.2.0-32-virtual{a}
  linux-tools-3.2.0-32{a}
(...)

The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
  libglib2.0-data shared-mime-info shared-mime-info:i386
87 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 103 MB of archives. After unpacking 151 MB will be used.
```

So there is difference between the two.

Could you please advice what I should choose to upgrade my server? Is there any advantages of upgrading additional packages via `aptitude` or I should stay with `apt-get` and upgrade less packages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the `apt-get` man page:

> **upgrade** is used to install the newest versions of all packages currently installed on the system.
>
> **dist-upgrade**, in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages.

When you use `aptitude`, it automatically use the dependencies of the packages, if you want likely the same results, use `apt-get dist-upgrade`.

If you want to know the differences between the two, check [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/935/24442) or [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/1749/92745).

Answer (score 5):

open your terminal and type this

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: you are welcome amigo . :D