# Update the system from terminal

Tags: command-line, kernel, updates

I want to update my Ubuntu 14.04 system from the terminal and I know that `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` are the commands but when I check the update manager kernel updates are still there. Why is that ? and what can I do to update the kernel from terminal.

Comment: dupe http://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade and http://askubuntu.com/questions/194651/why-use-apt-get-upgrade-instead-of-apt-get-dist-upgrade

Comment: @bain: It might be a dupe, but not of those, the answers are pretty much the same but not the sense of the question.

Comment: @Jobin how about http://askubuntu.com/questions/274557/update-manager-asking-me-to-update-kernel-but-apt-get-upgrade-does-not or http://askubuntu.com/questions/201706/how-can-i-make-apt-get-upgrade-the-kernel-similarly-to-aptitude

Comment: @bain: They are still specific to one package(the kernel) and this is a general concern. I wouldn't flag it as a dupe of those.

Comment: @Jobin Is this question not also specific to the kernel.. _" but when I check the update manager kernel updates are still there. Why is that ?"_

Comment: @bain: I guess they are, good catch.

Comment: @bain Why isn't this question the "dominant" question.  You've marked it as a duplicate, yet this is the question I ran into trying to solve an unrelated, general problem...and the supposed "dominant" question it is a 'duplicate' of is a question I never would have reached in a million years.

Comment: @bordeo I didn't mark this question as a duplicate - I just suggested some possibilities and some editors marked it as a duplicate. In general duplicates should be to questions that are older, have more upvotes/views and better answers. At the time this was flagged as a duplicate (2 years ago) the other questions probably were considered better by those metrics.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You need to perform `dist-upgrade` inorder to install/remove all dependencies related to the packages upgraded using `upgrade`. From the [manual page of apt-get](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get/):

> ```
>   dist-upgrade
>        dist-upgrade in addition to performing the function of
>        upgrade, also intelligently handles changing dependencies
>        with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart"
>        conflict resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade
>        the most important packages at the expense of less
>        important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade command may
>        therefore remove some packages. The /etc/apt/sources.list
>        file contains a list of locations from which to retrieve
>        desired package files. See also apt_preferences(5) for a
>        mechanism for overriding the general settings for
>        individual packages.
> ```

So, the better way of upgrading would be:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

However, be careful while using `dist-upgrade` as it might also remove packages to satisfy dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

apt-get upgrade won't install new software or remove software, something you must when installing a new kernel... See the thread.

A thing you can do (taken from [this thread, read full for more](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1218056)):

Use aptitude:

```
sudo aptitude update
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
sudo aptitude full-upgrade
```

You could also use `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` instead of `sudo apt-get upgrade`