# What's difference of apt-get and aptitude?

Tags: apt, aptitude

What is difference of `apt-get` and `aptitude`? Does both of them use same repositories?

Which one is better?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`aptitude` is supposed to be a user level program whereas `apt-get` is supposed to be *used by* higher level programs. It just turns out `apt-get` is easy to use so people just use it instead of the higher level managers like `aptitude` and `synaptic`.

`aptitude` is more user-friendly because it adds a layer of abstraction away from `apt-get`, `apt-cache` etc..; `apt-get` is more user-friendly than `dpkg` for the same reason. It's really down to the user's knowledge and what works best for them. `aptitude` and `apt-get` use the same repositories.  Let it be clear that `aptitude` does not itself run `apt-get` `apt-cache` etc.. I merely mean to point out that `aptitude` is a higher level package manager.

### The levels of abstraction:

- `aptitude` - High level of abstraction
- `apt-get`, `apt-cache`, etc.
- `dpkg` - Low level of abstraction

Comment: Also worth noting that `apt-get` often falls on its face for simple operations, and it has no ability to handle dependency mismatches or broken packages (although it claims that broken packages can be fixed with `apt-get install -f`, I've literally never seen that work in my entire life). For some reason, I use `apt-get` by default, but when it encounters problems, I usually end up resolving them with `aptitude`, which never seems to encounter `apt-get`'s numerous problems.

Comment: @weberc2, indeed thats true. I spent hours trying to fix problems with `-f` flag. Aptitude did it without any problem.

Comment: aptitude are frontend to dpkg, not apt-get.

Comment: "`apt-get` is supposed to be _used by_ higher level programs like `aptitude`." but then "Let it be clear that Aptitude does not itself use apt-get apt-cache etc."? What are you actually trying to say? If it only boils down to the idea that `aptitude` is "higher level", that's only true in a metaphorical - & subjective - sense. For example, if the idea is that it's "higher level" merely because it has all commands in one binary - well, `apt` can also do that. So this doesn't tell us anything really.

Comment: @underscore_d you were correct I have removed that from the answer as to avoid confusion, I wrote this answer a while ago.

Answer (score 14):

> `apt-get` and `aptitude` are both front ends to `dpkg`. Use one or the other
>   but be consistent. `aptitude` is newer and is suppose to be easier to
>   use. It also unifies some of the `apt-*` functions. You can use `aptitude`
>   to search and install while with `apt-*` you need `apt-get` and `apt-cache`
>   for installation and searching respectively.

Source: [Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/42967/on-ubuntu-why-sudo-apt-get-sometimes-and-sudo-aptitude-other-times)

Few other links you might like to read.

1. [Aptitude vs. apt-get: Which is the recommended (aka the “right”)
   tool to use?](https://superuser.com/questions/93437/aptitude-vs-apt-get-which-is-the-recommended-aka-the-right-tool-to-use)
2. [Is aptitude still considered superior to apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-still-considered-superior-to-apt-get)