# New apt tool vs. aptitude

Tags: apt, aptitude

Ubuntu Utopic has recently introduced a new package management frontend named `apt` ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man8/apt.8.html)) which provides a sort of high-level interface to tools `apt-get`, `apt-cache` and some other tools in the `apt-*` family.

Similar to this question [about `apt-get` vs. `aptitude`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1743/is-aptitude-still-considered-superior-to-apt-get), I am curious if `apt` is a real replacement for `aptitude` or if there are use cases that require `aptitude`?

---

As of 16.04, Xenial, installation command suggestions have changed from `apt-get install notinstalledpackage` to `apt install`.